Reflexive modules over finite extension ring
Let $R$ be a commutative normal domain, and $\Lambda$ be a module-finite $R$-algebra. Assume $\Lambda$ is reflexive as an $R$-module. My question is simple:
Question. If a finitely generated right $\Lambda$-module is reflexive as an $R$-module, does it necessarily reflexive as an $\Lambda$-module? What about the converse?
When considering module-finite algebras, I see people defining reflexive modules to be reflexive with respect to the base commutative ring, in order to obtain the so-called reflexive Morita equivalence [1]. On the other hand, it's natural to consider reflexive modules which is over the noncommutative ring, especially if the noncommutative ring has  good homological properties (e.g. if it is Auslander-Gorenstein, or more generally it satisfies the (2, 2)-condition [2]). So I'm just wondering whether the two definitions are related.
[1] Iyama, Osamu; Reiten, Idun, Fomin-Zelevinsky mutation and tilting modules over Calabi-Yau algebras., Am. J. Math. 130, No. 4, 1087-1149 (2008). ZBL1162.16007.
[2] Norihiro Hanihara (Kavli IPMU), Reflexive modules over Auslander-Gorenstein rings (abstract https://s-murai.w.waseda.jp/meetings/CA2023/Hanihara.pdf)
